# Numpy append matrix

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```py
import numpy as np

a = [np.array([[0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.48657015, 0.81184143, 0.03247722, 0.68119226, 0.15978291], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467], [0.33501576, 0.99523939, 0.7630373 , 0.19439633, 0.70525067]]), np.array([[0.81469143, 0.53749789, 0.77798275, 0.97920433, 0.08317034], [0.21156496, 0.73393373, 0.27911978, 0.6488366 , 0.94080104], [0.33987569, 0.43004961, 0.32322977, 0.88149818, 0.88137525], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467], [0.33501576, 0.99523939, 0.7630373 , 0.19439633, 0.70525067]]), np.array([[0.81469143, 0.53749789, 0.77798275, 0.97920433, 0.08317034], [0.21156496, 0.73393373, 0.27911978, 0.6488366 , 0.94080104], [0.33987569, 0.43004961, 0.32322977, 0.88149818, 0.88137525], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467]])]
b = []

for x in a:
    if x.shape[0] < max([x.shape[0] for x in a]):
        x = np.concatenate([x, np.zeros((1,5))])
        b.append(x)
print(b)
```

Matrix `a` has 3 arrays with different shapes

1. 6x5
2. 7x5
3. 6x5

After appending those matrices to `b` it has just 2 arrays, and it's missing the longer array.
How can I fix this? Any tips?

matrix b =

```
[array([[0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548],
        [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196],
        [0.48657015, 0.81184143, 0.03247722, 0.68119226, 0.15978291],
        [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548],
        [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467],
        [0.33501576, 0.99523939, 0.7630373 , 0.19439633, 0.70525067],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]),
 array([[0.81469143, 0.53749789, 0.77798275, 0.97920433, 0.08317034],
        [0.21156496, 0.73393373, 0.27911978, 0.6488366 , 0.94080104],
        [0.33987569, 0.43004961, 0.32322977, 0.88149818, 0.88137525],
        [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196],
        [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548],
        [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])]
```

Comment: 1) I'm not quite following what's intended to happen. At a high level, do you mind describing the intent of the code above? 2) Can you make the above code reproducible, by defining the contents of a?

Comment: basically I am trying to add zeros to the two arrays the 6x5 ones to match the 7x5 one, so just adding one row to them to match, but the matrix b instead of 3 arrays, showing only 2 with the zeros added

Comment: I see - have you noticed that `b.append(x)` is inside the if, so it will only run if it's appending zeros to the array? Based on your description, it seems like it should be indented one layer less. Speaking of which, do you mind fixing the indentation in your code? As written it has a syntax error.

Comment: a = [6x5 , 7x5 , 6x5] trying to add one row (zeros) to the 6x5 ones to match the 7x5 , but b showing after concatenating only 2 arrays

Comment: Can you provide explicit input/output examples for clarity?

Comment: While its save to use, don't use the variable name x in two different loops.

Comment: maybe I could fix the issue with else?

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `b.append(x)` line outside the if, you will always append the matrix to b.

E.g.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [np.array([[0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.48657015, 0.81184143, 0.03247722, 0.68119226, 0.15978291], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467], [0.33501576, 0.99523939, 0.7630373 , 0.19439633, 0.70525067]]), np.array([[0.81469143, 0.53749789, 0.77798275, 0.97920433, 0.08317034], [0.21156496, 0.73393373, 0.27911978, 0.6488366 , 0.94080104], [0.33987569, 0.43004961, 0.32322977, 0.88149818, 0.88137525], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467], [0.33501576, 0.99523939, 0.7630373 , 0.19439633, 0.70525067]]), np.array([[0.81469143, 0.53749789, 0.77798275, 0.97920433, 0.08317034], [0.21156496, 0.73393373, 0.27911978, 0.6488366 , 0.94080104], [0.33987569, 0.43004961, 0.32322977, 0.88149818, 0.88137525], [0.9646295 , 0.06550677, 0.44371316, 0.86679069, 0.63022196], [0.70194773, 0.55555815, 0.19743302, 0.18483827, 0.21742548], [0.24750262, 0.20405816, 0.75160551, 0.41791071, 0.41336467]])]
b = []

max_rows = max([x.shape[0] for x in a])
for x in a:
    if x.shape[0] < max_rows:
        x = np.concatenate([x, np.zeros((1,5))])
    b.append(x)
```

Gives a 3 element list, all of which have the same shape (7x5.)

Comment: thanks , its working now, appreciate it